# Documentation on Clustering API Manager 1.6

Tags: wso2

Does the documentation on clustering for API Manager (http://docs.wso2.org/display/Cluster/Creating+a+Cluster) also applies for version 1.6? The documentation talks about version 1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That guide is applicable for products based on carbon 4.1.0. For API Manager 1.5.0 and 1.6.0 please refer to http://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager